# ReactDnd-Cannot Send State from useDrag to useDrop

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I have a problem about my project.
I want to send created State via "onDragStart" and send its ID through useDrag to useDrop but in use Drop I got empty object.
can u guys help me ?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: please i need a developer who can contact me in person via email or somthing.